# Getting nested data out of JSON in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have some JSON with Two objects and these each have 3 objects nested.

`{
    "FirstPerson": {
        "number": "101",
        "a10": "1001",
        "a20": "1002" 
    },
    "SecondPerson": {
        "number": "102",
        "a10": "2001",
        "a20": "2001" 
    }
}`

In c# asp.net mvc2 I've been able to get to "FirstPerson" or "SecondPerson" using a Hashtable but how do I get to "number" or "a10" when I know "FirstPerson"?

e.g. an objects inside an object.

Is a Hashtable the best use for this or should I be using something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the JSON object to a dynamic variable and access the properties that way (only in C# 4.0 though)

```
dynamic jsonData = jsonObject;
int workflowNum = jsonData.SecondPerson[0].workflow;
```

Comment: Using DeserializeObject to get the jsonObject?

Comment: That or using JSON.NET to get the JSONObject and assign it to a dynamic variable.  JSON.NET usage: http://blog.petegoo.com/archive/0001/01/01/using-json.net-to-eval-json-into-a-dynamic-variable-in.aspx and JsonReader usage: http://www.nikhilk.net/CSharp-Dynamic-Programming-JSON.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I found that solution for your problem may be give a clue to solve that

Want to convert a C# object into it's JSON equivalent? Here is a simple object from the System.Web.Script namespace that does exactly that:

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer . It is stored in the System.Web.Extentions DLL (.Net Framework 3.5 only)

Using this object we serialize and deserialize  objects in C#. Here is a quick sample:

A simple Employee object:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }   
}
```

Adding some instances of them to a List:

Employee oEmployee1 =

```
   new Employee{Name="Pini",ID="111", Age="30"};
```

Employee oEmployee2 =

```
  new Employee { Name = "Yaniv", ID = "Cohen", Age = "31" };
```

Employee oEmployee3 =

```
    new Employee { Name = "Yoni", ID = "Biton", Age = "20" };
```

List oList = new List()

```
{ oEmployee1, oEmployee2, oEmployee3 };
```

Serializing then:

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);

And here is the output:

```
[{"Name":"Pini","Age":"30","ID":"111"},

{"Name":"Yaniv","Age":"31","ID":"Cohen"},

{"Name":"Yoni","Age":"20","ID":"Biton"}]
```

For your consideration here is the link http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: This is very close but I want to Deserialize.

Comment: And the Deserialize method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx isn't good enough... because ?

Answer (score 2):

I have had good results using JsonConvert. It seems to do a good job of knowing what to do with collections. Just define the class you want to de-serialize to and have at it.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Example:

`MyCollection col = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCollection>(this.HttpContext.Request.Params[0]);`

Where MyCollection is a class which contains a collection of, in your case, people.